# Why does my Apache HttpComponents's HttpGet request hang?

Tags: java, java-8, apache-httpcomponents

I have this code, and it works fine:

```
System.out.println("Fetching...");
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://blogs.reuters.com/talesfromthetrail/2012/06/26/obama-letter-brings-democratic-donors-out-of-the-woodwork/");
CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) {
    System.out.println("Fetched!");
    return EntityUtils.toString(entity);
}
```

but apparently using `EntityUtils` to convert the entity to String is not recommended. So I tried to use a `StringBuffer` like the example code does:

```
System.out.println("Fetching...");
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://blogs.reuters.com/talesfromthetrail/2012/06/26/obama-letter-brings-democratic-donors-out-of-the-woodwork/");
CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) {
    System.out.println("Fetched!");
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line = rd.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        result.append(line);
        line = rd.readLine();
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

and it hangs! The `"Fetched!"` print statement didn't even get to execute. I'm a Java noob so I have no idea why this is the case. How should I be debugging this?

Comment: Which versions are you using? I tried it with Java 1.8.0_51 and HTTPClient 4.5 and it works.

Comment: i'm using the same versions as you do

Comment: Adding something like `request.setConfig(RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(10000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(10000).build());` might give you an indication of why it is hanging because either connecting to the source or retrieving the data will timeout and an exception is thrown.

Comment: The other possibility is that response.getEntity() returns null, if the response does not contain a body. try printing the the response code first: `response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()`